# programming different behaviour for first iteration in loop

Tags: java, loops

I have a Collection of objects I need to iterate over. The collection is of variable size. If the collection has more than 1 object in it, I need to perform special processing on objects 2 .. infinity.

What's the preferred method to do this? For example:

```
int count = 1;

for (CustomObject co : CustomObjectCollection) {
    methodAll(co);

    if(count > 1) {
        methodSpecial(co);
    }

    count = count++;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you have will work except for one bug: `count = count++` does absolutely nothing.  `count = count + 1` would work, or `count++`, but  `count = count++` is a no-op.

Comment: @Ascalonian: Yes, I mentioned that.

Comment: There are several ways to do it, with various performance/readability tradeoffs, but there's no way to do it that's strictly better in all respects.  Think of this as being _a_ best way.

Answer (score 5):

You could also just use a boolean flag if you don't specifically need to track the count.

```
boolean first = true;
for (CustomObject co : CustomObjectCollection) {
    methodAll(co);
    if (!first) {
      methodSpecial(co);
    }
    first = false;
}
```

#### Which to use

Which to use depends on your specific use case. Assuming that you are not looking to optimise every last op-per-second of performance then *go with the option that declares your intent*:

1. `count++` is fine if you want to track or use the count outside the loop (as per Louis' answer, it is `count++`, not `count = count++`)
2. `for(int i = 0; i < collection.size(); i++)` is good as well if the collection supports a `get(i)` operation. This also lets you skip the first item by initialising `int i` to a different index. It might be used if you don't want the extra count variable hanging around outside the loop.
3. the above `boolean first = true;` (or the inverse `boolean notFirst = false;`) highlight that you want to treat the first and subsequent elements differently
4. If you have the List interface on your collection and want to skip a set number of elements, then [`subList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList(int,%20int)) is a good option

#### Performance

If performance is a concern, then *measure it for your platform and implementation*, but from general experience, from slowest to fastest, with <=20x difference between the first and last:

1. for each loop with iterator: slowest
2. `for(int i = 0; i < list.size() ; i++)`
3. declare `int size = list.size()` then a `for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)` loop

However these speed results depend on so many things that unless performance is a design goal or an identified issue go with the iterator until you have a reason to use one of the other two - the iterator is generally fast enough.

Answer (score 0):

I think a better way to do this would be to work directly with the iterator like so:

```
Iterator<CustomObject> it = customObjectCollection.iterator();

if(it.hasNext()) { //first pass don't call methodSpecial
    methodAll(it.next());
}

CustomObject customObj;
while(it.hasNext()) { //all the rest 2..infinity
    customObj = it.next();
    methodAll(customObj);
    methodSpecial(customObj);
}
customObj = null; // for garbage collection
```

This way you don't have to check each iteration if this is the first run or not.
This will work with any `Iterable` (which is already needed for a `foreach` loop anyway).

Note: If this is not an ordered collection you might get different elements in the first iteration then you might expect.

Comment: This is interesting, but I'm not sure why my solution wouldn't work with any Iterable.

Comment: It would. I'm not saying a `foreach` loop wouldn't work with any `Iterable`, I'm saying this would as well.